# Not able to delete Perforce CL with shelved files

Tags: java, perforce

I am using the com.perforce.p4java.server package for running perforce commands.
I am using the deletePendingChangelist(id) function of server class but it fails giving error that "CL has shelved files" and you don't have permission.

Any idea how to delete a CL with shelved files using server class. Also, how to ensure whether I have appropriate permission or not?

Comment: You need to use the `shelve -d` command to delete the shelved files from the changelist.  If you are not the owner of the changelist, you need admin-level permissions and you need to use the `-f` flag as well.

Comment: @Samwise Any idea how can we do shelve -d using com.perforce.p4java.server ?

Comment: You'd have to consult the P4Java docs.  There's always a direct mapping between P4Java function calls and server commands (because P4Java just runs normal server commands behind the scenes) but it's not always obvious what P4Java function name to search for.  I'd look for any function that has to do with updating a shelf and then see if you can find the "delete files" option associated with it...